# How do I kill someone with the repair tool?

Tags: battlefield-3

I got the Back to Karkland map pack, and it added new "Assignments," which are like little quests you can do to unlock guns.

For the engineer assignment, one of the tasks is to kill someone with the repair tool... do any of you have any advice for going about this? I'm under the impression the repair tool does almost no damage (though I could be wrong).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It takes a few seconds, during which you're relatively vulnerable, so sneaking up on someone (especially a sniper who isn't paying attention) makes this considerably easier.  You may want to try to sneak behind enemy lines so that you can catch people with their back to you.  Here's a video of a guy doing just that:

Comment: looks like it does plenty of damage from that video

Comment: Well, considering the other weapons you have to choose from include *sharp bits of metal flying at high speed into soft, vulnerable flesh*, I guess setting their butt on fire seems like it would be more "irritating" than "instantly lethal."

Comment: gotta admire his efforts at lighting their crotch on fire though

Comment: It does take a certain "je ne sais quoi" to roast some "marshmallows" with a blowtorch.

Answer (score 1):

I actually got lucky in my plan on it.  I just played Team Death Match on Noshahr Canals.  The smaller team death match maps pack people together closer, and the creates on this map allow you too move, but also people will stop and either hide, wait for their health to go back up, or camp in them.  Found a guy just standing still in a create and flamed him....